# How to get my hat back on?

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

On the middle of the first mission, while fighting aliens, I lost my hat.

Now I've ended the mission, thinking it would come back, but no, I still don't have it.

Is there a way to get my hat back?

Comment: As far as I know, you either pick it up right away after it falls or you risk losing it forever

Which is really weird, considering that you have a hat rack in your office, where you should have an endless hat supply

Comment: @Dracgnar: You should consider posting your comment as a answer, I never got my hat back, even after finishing the game, reloading the save, and a huge number of full reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you either pick it up right away after it falls or you risk losing it forever. Which is really weird, considering that you have a hat rack in your office, where you should have an endless hat supply

Comment: +1, after doing some searches, I found many people who had lost their hat forever, as well as some who had immediately rescued theirs.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest starting over the game. (off and on)

However, if that didn't work, then it was probably a certain button/key that you pressed.

Other than that, it's best that an alien shot off your hat. :3